# href to datatables row

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatables

I have two datatables in the first one, a column contains a string with a `href=#id` of a row in the second datatable.
Getting the Id works fine but the problem I'm having is how to show the row when it's in another page that is not shown.

code of the first table row:

```
{% for item in items %}
..
<td>
<a href={{'#'~item.0}}>{{item.1}}</a>
</td>
...
{% endif %}
```

Code of the second table row

```
{% for item in items %} 
   <tr id={{item.0}} >
     <td class="gradeA">{{item.0}}</td>
     <td class="gradeC"> {{item.1}}</td>
     <td id="itemDesc" class="gradeC"> {{item.2}}</td>
     <td class="gradeX"> {{item.3}} </td>
     <td class="gradeU"> {{item.4}} </td>
   </tr> 
{% endfor %}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var 1stTable = $('#firstTable').dataTable(..);
   var 2ndTable = $('#secondTable').dataTable(..);
} );
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.  Show us what you've tried, please.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @cale_b I just did :) thank you for your asnwer